# Flitering Previous Index with List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to figure out how to make a list in Python using list comprehension that includes items that has a type of string and begins with "Test_1", "Test_2", "Test_3" or "Test_4" or is an integer that is preceded by a string. I also want to make sure that all strings are equal to "Test_1" or "Test_2" or "Test_3" or "Test_4".

However, I am not sure how to check if the item is preceded by a string.

For example, I have the following list.

```
['Test_3', 80, 'Test_4', 80, 90, 'Test_1', 0, 'Test_2', 0]
```

And I want to convert it to this.

```
['Test_3', 80, 'Test_4', 80, 'Test_1', 0, 'Test_2', 0]
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
column = [x for x in column if type(x) is str and x == "Test_1" or x == "Test_2" or x == "Test_3" or x == "Test_4" or type(x) is int]
```

Any ideas? Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Can you give us example input and the output you would like to generate from the input?

Comment: @larsks Just edited my original question! Thanks for helping!

Comment: You never have two strings following each other?

Comment: can you work on your scenario to clarify more like, 1. how many occurrence one should expect between two strings i.e. `0` or `1` or `0 or more` or `1 or more` or `maximum 2`

Comment: @Gahan There will only be one number preceding another. There will never be three numbers in a row.

Comment: @IgorRivin Nope, never two strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
columns = [x for i, x in enumerate(column) if (i==0 and isinstance(x,(int,str))) or (isinstance(x,str) and isinstance(column[i-1], int)) or (isinstance(x,int) and isinstance(column[i-1],str))]
```

It takes a list `column`, then check the previous element and the current element and pick it only if it is a str-int pair or int-str pair

Comment: Does this remove consecutive strings too?

Comment: yes, it does. The condition requires str follows int or other way round.

Comment: forgot to say, I only want this for integers and not strings, but I'll play around with what you wrote to get it to my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

column = ['Test_3', 80, 'Test_4', 80, 90, 'Test_1', 0, 'Test_2', 0]
[list(g)[0] for _, g in groupby(column,lambda x:isinstance(x,int))]
#['Test_3', 80, 'Test_4', 80, 'Test_1', 0, 'Test_2', 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
import itertools
pairlist = [[column[i], column[i+1]] for i in range(len(column)-1)]
goodpairlist = [i for i in pairlist if isinstance(i[0], str)]
list(itertools.chain(*goodpairlist)
```